# A problem when I use enclosing functions with global/nonlocal variables in Python3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I want to figure out how does the enclosing function work, and I run three code blocks as below.

*****************************************Block 1*****************************************

```
def a1_(r):
    r+=1
    res = 0
    print('a1_res=',id(res))
    def a2(r):
        global res
        print('res = ',res)
        print('a2_res=',id(res))
        res+=r
        return res
    return a2(r)

a1_(1)
```

it cannot work and the error is NameError: name 'res' is not defined which occurred in Line 6.

***************************************Block 2***************************************

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    def foo2():
        global a
        print(a)
        a+=1
        return a
    return foo2()
foo()
```

it is work without any error.

***************************************Block 3***************************************

I replaced the 'global' to 'nonlocal' in Block 1, it works!

```
def a1_(r):
    r+=1
    res = 0
    print('a1_res=',id(res))
    def a2(r):
        nonlocal res
        print('res = ',res)
        print('a2_res=',id(res))
        res+=r
        return res
    return a2(r)

a1_(1)
```

Just feeling quite confused, because The structure bewteen block 1 and block 2 is similar. However, block 2 works but block 1 not.

Also, I just replaced 'global' by 'nonlocal' in block 3, it works.(PS: In my opinion, the effect of global and nonlocal is the same)

Could someone help me to figure it out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell Block 2 shouldn't work as well, at least it doesn't for me. You can use `print(globals())` to see which variables are in the global namespace.

For both Block 1 and Block 2 you try to access a variable in the global namespace which only works if you defined that variable in that namespace.

For Block 3 you are using nonlocal to access a variable in the outer namespace. If you search for python namespaces in a search engineyou can probably learn more about what you are investigating (for example [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) or [this](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/)).

Edit: `NameError: name 'res' is not defined` tells you that this variable is not defined in the relevant namespace. Calling `global res` tells Python is okay even if `res` isn't defined in the global namespace from before, but before using it it needs to be defined thus the line causing the error should be `print('res = ', res)` as here `res` is not defined in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and references! So, the reason is that local function cannot modify the global variables 'res' because the code "global res" in my local function. And in my local function, it only can modify the variables which are in enclosing function or itself.  In other words, the local functions cannot modify any global variables. Am i understanding correctly?

Comment: With `global res` you can modify the global variable `res`, the problem is that the global variable `res` is not defined. If you would have defined `res` outside of both functions or in the inner function before you first tried use it (the print statement) then there wouldn't be a problem.